# Web application using OWIN and NancyFX how to make it public

Tags: owin, katana, nancy

I have created A simple website using [OWIN](http://owin.org/) and [NancyFX](http://nancyfx.org/) as a learning experience.  Now i want to make my website avaliable public or at least on my local network(i want to share my experience with my company team).

My question how to configure that:

1. in case of using `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` as the Host and Server.
2. Or in case of using `OwinHost.exe` as host and `Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener` as server.

Answer (score 1):

1. Microsoft.Owin.Host.Systemweb : It is still a web hosted (IIS) application. You can consider using Azure web sites to host your application.
2. In case of Owinhost.exe -- Owinhost.exe is simply the self host option. Today Owinhost is mostly useful for development time experience. When it comes to production deployment it may not be efficient to start the Owinhost.exe process on a server in command line. Managing the owinhost may not be very efficient. Alternatively you can host the same application in a worker role (in case of azure) or a windows service. In this case you don't need the Owinhost.exe. [This](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Selfhosting&referringTitle=Documentation) document has some pointers on self-host packages.

In future there may be a way to host your self hosted application on IIS directly (instead of systemweb). [Here](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Nov/23/Checking-out-the-Helios-IIS-Owin-Web-Server-Host) are some pointers about the same. Advantage of this model is - you get some of the benefits of IIS for free like process management. Note: This is still in a prototype stage.

Comment: I already implemented the first approach. But from your answer i understand that self-host `Owinhost.exe` is used mainly for development/testing, right?. Thanks for answering

Comment: Yes. Here is an article about using Owinhost custom server from VS 2013 : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/09/11/visual-studio-2013-custom-web-servers-and-owinhost-exe.aspx.